# В чем смысл упаковки нескольких маленьких чисел в int32\64?

Tags: c++

Недавно познакомился с упаковкой нескольких маленьких чисел в int32\64.
В одних из исходников что я нашёл был упакована дата (год, месяц, день) в 32 битное число, в другое 32 числа (часы, минуты, секунды) времени, а потом это всё упаковано в одно общее 64 битное число.
Тут нетрудно догадаться, что это лишние операции с маской и сдвигом, а лишние операции это лишнее время на выполнение.

В чем смысл такой упаковки о которой описал выше?

Или **более общий вопрос** (в случае если ответ на вопрос выше типо "*Резоны автора кода что ты нашёл*"). Вообще в чем смысл упаковки любых чисел и когда она может быть полезна?

P.s. есть мысли по поводу сокрытия инфы, но разве ради этого стоит тратить время на выполнение? *(вопрос риторический, если я не ошибся конечно же)*

Comment: Ну, например, при правильной упаковке сравнение будет выполняться куда как быстрее. Чем не резон?

Comment: Тут от контекста зависит, если с временем - то для поиска быстрее сравнить 2 упакованных числа разом, чем плодить if (...>=...) { if (...>=...) { if (...>=...) { ..... }}} Но я бы всё-равно так не делал, ибо возрастает вероятность человеческой ошибки.

Comment: @Akina ,@Blackmeser не думал об этом,буду знать,спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Конкретно для времени**, дело скорее всего кроется в [BCD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)

Первая и главная причина что-то куда-то паковать - наличие векторных инструкций у процессора:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Остальные причины также косвенно завязаны на железо - если какая-то железка типа часов отдает время в таком вот формате ([BCD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)), то его могут и не декодировать, а так и таскать по системе дальше.

Comment: Уточните, это касается стандартных упаковок, например 4 Word в 1 Int64 ?

Comment: Ну да. Сидят 4 байта подряд в массиве. Компилятор это видит. И если ему дозволено, пишет код, которых хряпает их за раз.

Answer (score 4):

Навскидку, упаковка может быть полезна тогда, когда:

- гораздо чаще нужно сравнивать композитные сущности между собой, чем смотреть на их компоненты. Код сравнения будет гораздо короче и быстрее;
- при ограничениях на свободное (дисковое) пространство;
- при передаче данных по медленным каналам;
- не важна, или даже нежелательна человеко-читаемость.

---

Кстати, вот вы пишете *"операции с маской и сдвигом"*, а упакованы они как? Если упаковка идет строго по байтам, и тогда, к каждому компоненту можно обратиться просто разыменуя смещенный указатель на него.

Comment: Число сдвигается на n байт влево для упаковки,а распаковка происходит путём полученного числа умноженного на маску и итоговый результат сдвигается на n байт вправо

Comment: То есть по байтам - тогда ответ @gbg еще более актуален.